# How to manipulate the small context menu of ios in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad

I have a content-editable div. So it basically functions like a text editor. I have a toolbar of my own which has different buttons. Now when the user types some text in an iPad and then  selects the text a small system generated menu pops up which has options like cut copy paste etc. Now this hides some of my toolbar button. So what i want to know is that is there any way that i can decide the position of this menu? I would not like to stop the menu from appearing but just reposition it. Please Help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i tried to disable the property -webkit-user-select: none !important; at run-time when a specific event comes, but that does'nt work. I think because once the menu has come there seems to be no way to make it disappear. Also i don't want to permanently disable the context menu. In the end i just took the decision of showing the toolbar at the bottom. But waiting for some way this can be done